# MySQL upgrade to 5.6.4 from 5.6.33 on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, ubuntu, upgrade

I just upgraded our MySQL server from 5.5.53 by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Which got me to version 5.6.33

However, I'm looking to get to at least 5.6.4 where it appears the DATETIME datatype takes up 37.5% less space ([per this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time)).

I can't seem to figure out / find how to upgrade from 5.6.33 to 5.6.4.  Can anyone help?

FYI - I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  Let me know if you need any other relevant data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks, I got this response: `This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.6.33, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade`.  Not sure how to decipher that, I'm pretty new to all of this.

Comment: The internal format of `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` changed.  During the upgrade process, `mysql_upgrade` will (optionally?) rebuild the tables.  `DATETIME` changed from 8 bytes to 5; `TIMESTAMP` changed from 4 to 5.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are wrong.

MySQL 5.6.33 is bigger than 5.6.4

For more information look at MySQL 5.6 release note:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/

MySQL 5.6.4 released at 2011-12-20 So MySQL 5.6.33 has already DateTime feature.

Comment: That would be incredibly confusing.  That said, when comparing my table sizes, they are identical.  I would have expected a decrease in size.

Comment: I think you should Alter tables that have datetime column for use new datetime format. look at this topic http://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-old-mysql-5-5-format-temporals-to-mysql-5-6-format-2/

Comment: Ok, I'll have to dig into that before accepting this answer, but I appreciate the information.